# Wordpress CPT UI and ACF custom fields

Tags: wordpress

i am using CPT UI for custom post type and ACF custom fields. 
i have created custom post type (companies) and linked to its custom fields. In admin everything is okay. I want to display this in front end. The user can be enter the company details also. How can i display this in front end ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
    $id = get_the_ID();
    $data = get_field('custom_field_name', $id);
    echo $data;
?>
```

Obviously this will need a lot of refinement to look good but that's the basics on how to retrieve data from an ACF field.  You may need to `var_dump($data);` in order to figure out how to get the part you want (if it's not just storing a string).  Without more details on what you're doing that's a good an answer as I can give you.